# Having problems with code I wrote to get inverse of a matrix for each nonzero element and 0 to 0

Tags: python

I am totally new to programming, and I have written this function function to take a matrix and maps each nonzero element to its inverse and zero to zero in python. Here is my code:

```
def question_1_c(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        row_arr = []
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            row_arr.append(1/ arr[i][j])
        new_arr.append(row_arr)
    return new_arr

question_1_c([[70,0,13,67],[90,48,57,26],[43,45,67,89],[88,65,44,23]])
```

For some reason it gives an error. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you handling the 0 case in your code? What error do you get where?

Comment: What error does it give you? Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array has a 0 value, in [0,1] position... so in

1/ arr[i][j] the program do:
1/0, and that throw an exception.

You must consider this case do somethig like this:

```
if arr[i][j]==0:
    ...
else:
    row_arr.append(1/ arr[i][j])
```

Answer (score 1):

The error that I got was a divide by zero, which makes sense because you're never checking for zero values. You're also doing integer division - which will not do what you expect it to do.

Also, in Python you can iterate over collections. I've rewritten your code, and this *should* do what you expect it to do.

```
def question_1_c(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for row in arr:
        row_arr = []
        for val in row:
            if val:
                row_arr.append(1.0/val)
            else:
                row_arr.append(val)
        new_arr.append(row_arr)
    return new_arr
```